# Let $H$ be a nonempty subset of group $G$. Show that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $[H]=H$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I know that the set of all elements of $G$ which can be expressed by

$$a_1^{m_1}\cdots a_r^{m_r}, \ \ a_i\in H, \ m_i\in \mathbb{Z}, $$

denoted by $[H]$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ and $H \subseteq [H] $. My difficulty is to prove the other inclusion. The question is from a Brazilian book called Álgebra Moderna, 5th edition.

I also have the 4th, where there is another question in the same position that asks to show that every subgroup which contains $H$ also contains $[H]$

So I really don't know if there is an error in the 5th ed or it's on me. Any hints please, because I can't even prove that $e$ belongs to, let's say,  an arbitrary $H=\{a_1,\dots, a_n\} \subset G$.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

after correct a few mistakes, pointed out from the mates, I think I have the solution. Since $H$ is a subgroup, every $x\in[H]$ is a product of powers of the elements of $H$. Therefore $x\in H$ and $H=[H]$.

Comment: I think you should include the defintion of what $[H]$ is in the question.

Comment: You haven't used $S$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron included.

Comment: Your first "I know" is wrong. This is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $H$.

Comment: And moreover $H\subseteq [H]$ and not vice versa.

Comment: If I understand correctly: $H$ is a set of elements and $[H]$ is supposed to be the subgroup generated by those elements?

Comment: @Clayton that's right,